# How get Type of attribute from reStructuredText?

Tags: python, restructuredtext

How get Type of attribute from reStructuredText?
I have something like this.

```
@property
def port(self):
    """Get port.

    :return: port
    :rtype: str
    """
    return self._port
```

How can i get type of attribute (str)?

Comment: Why do you want to do this ?

Comment: i need it like type for databese

Comment: Then you're barking at the wrong tree. Docstrings are for humans, not for metaprogramming, and relying on doctrsing parsing would be brittle at best.  If you want something reliable, you'll have to write a proper attribute->sql type mapping.

Comment: because i have 500MHz procesor ... i need pure sql

Comment: Doesn't make any difference. What I meant is that you should not try to programatically parse the docstrings to infer type but code it plain an simply in your code, like with a `property:type` dict for each relevant class or some similar mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the code fragment yours? If yes, you can use whatever mechanics you like, e.g. add an attribute directly to the function for later inspection: `SomeClass.port.fget.return_type = int`. Try it, it works. Only be careful to qualify the property via the class, not via the instance (or use `.__class__` on an instance).

If not, [parse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12883428/223424) the `port.__doc__` and extract the relevant field.

If you are CPU-constrained, you can still use e.g. SQLAlchemy without the ORM layer. It can produce very efficient SQL from table models *ahead of time,* e.g. during startup. Then you just invoke them with right parameters, paying rather little CPU time. In most cases, the DB round-trip dwarfs the query creation and results decoding anyway.

Same applies to parsing the RST: you can do it ahead of time, e.g. as a build step, and store the information in an easy-to-parse file, e.g. JSON or even as pickled Python data, and quickly load it as startup.