# Can I call sphinx.parsers.Parser() directly and parse a fragment of reST?

Tags: python, parsing, python-sphinx

I need to parse a stand-alone fragment of reST content to a doctree (for later processing).  I can do it via docutils easily enough, e.g.:

```
# ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883428/

import docutils.nodes
import docutils.parsers.rst
import docutils.utils

def parse_rst(text: str) -> docutils.nodes.document:
    parser = docutils.parsers.rst.Parser()
    components = (docutils.parsers.rst.Parser,)
    settings = docutils.frontend.OptionParser(
    components=components).get_default_values()
    document = docutils.utils.new_document('<rst-doc>', settings=settings)
    parser.parse(text, document)
    return document

class MyVisitor(docutils.nodes.NodeVisitor):

    def visit_reference(self, node: docutils.nodes.reference) -> None:
        """Called for "reference" nodes."""
        print(node)

    def unknown_visit(self, node: docutils.nodes.Node) -> None:
        """Called for all other node types."""
        print(node)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doc = parse_rst('spam spam lovely spam')
    visitor = MyVisitor(doc)
    doc.walk(visitor)
```

That works unless the reST content includes Sphinx-specific directives/roles (e.g. `.. glossary::`, `:term:`, etc). 
So I need the Sphinx parser rather than the docutils one.

I tried subclassing `sphinx.parsers.Parser`; using `from sphinx.application import Sphinx` then `app.build()` to fake a sphinx docs project.

But references and workarounds get complicated so I suspect I'm approaching it the wrong way.  Can I use the sphinx parser outside of the full-blown `sphinx-build` workflow?

Comment: [tk0miya](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2922#issuecomment-243491972) says "Unfortunately, Sphinx is a monolithic application. So there is no way to use only parsers."